# 7990 next to a R9 280x heat

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, cooling

I'm considering buying a second graphics card and plugging it along side my R9 280x. What I'm wondering about is if this will cause too much stress on the PCIe bus in regards to heat?

I've got plenty of cooling for the cards itself (antec 1200 fully fitted with fans), but I'm a bit worried the stress it wil put on the motherboard. Should I be worried or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, motherboards are generally designed for this sort of thing. As are GPUs, in fact if you had a GPU with extreme cooling requirements its physical size would probably prevent you from placing another GPU in close proximity.

One of the systems I use for work has 4 GPUs in it... what you ***do*** have to worry about, however, is the spacing between the PCIe slots and the card profile. Many of the highest-end GPUs take two (sometimes 2.5 - 3) slots for their cooling solution. This means you may need a larger form factor chassis for 2 of these GPUs.

You also have to worry about the number of PCIe lanes exposed by each of the slots. Referring back to the 4 GPU configuration, only one of the cards runs at x16; the other three are x8. In a 2x configuration, the motherboard is capable of hosting 2 x16 GPUs, provided you put them in the proper slots.

#### The motherboard used is an ASUS [RAMPAGE IV EXTREME](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/RAMPAGE_IV_EXTREME/):

[image]

Notice the spacing between the red PCIe slots? This motherboard is specifically designed for 4-way GPU configurations, and even so to utilize 4 GPUs you have to sacrifice the black general-purpose PCIe slot sandwiched in-between. This means no dedicated raid, network or audio cards...

Granted, you are discussing a situation with only two GPUs but these are all the things you have to consider when you install multiple GPUs. The 4 GPU configuration just makes them blatantly obvious.